# Algebraically Independence and Algebraic Extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If $A=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is the polynomial ring over $K$, and $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}\subset A$ such that $K(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ is algebraic over $K(f_1,\dots,f_n)$, then is $\{f_1,\dots f_n\}$ algebraically independent over $K$?

It is better if this can be done without some other lemmas or theorems.

Comment: Is $K$ a field? I believe this can be made to hold for an arbitrary commutative ring $K$, if "algebraic over" is replaced by "integral over" and if the round parentheses are replaced by square brackets. But I don't know a proof. The method from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144567/can-transcedence-degree-be-defined-for-arbitrary-ring-homomorphism/144625#144625 gets close but not quite there.